# How to count the occurrence of every digit in a given input?

Tags: c

Hi im trying to write a program that can read a line and counts the occurrence of every digit (e.g. a2bc8c45v28 should gives 0020110020).
I came up with the following program:

```
int main() {
int t;
int count[10]={};
while(scanf("%*c%1d", &t)==1){
    printf("%d\n",t);
    count[t]++;
}
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) printf("%d ",count[i]);
return 0;
```

}

However this gives an incorrect output it skips some digits.
Can anybody explain why this is happening?

Comment: Why are you using scanf?  This problem screams `getchar`

Comment: I see no sensible relationship between the example input, and its supposed output. They aren't even the same length.

Comment: `%*c` reads exactly one char and discards it.  It is not a wildcard type glob that discards multiple inputs.

Comment: As pointed out, you need to change your while loop. An easy solution is to read every character until newline; during each iteration check if the character `ch` is a digit (you can use `isdigit` from `ctype.h`). If `ch` is a digit, increment the respective count using this ASCII trick - `++count[ch - '0']`. So, you can replace your while loop like this: `while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') if (isdigit(ch)) ++count[ch - '0'];`

Comment: `int count[10]={};` is not valid Standard C. You are either using a compiler for C with extras or a compiler for a different language.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` is absolutely the wrong tool for this.  To explain what is happening, you just need to walk through it and understand the format string.  ("Understand the format string", unfortunately, is the root cause of 99% of scanf confusion.)

The format string "%*c%1d" will match (and discard) one byte. If the second byte is a digit it will match.  On the input `a2`, scanf will return 1 and leave the file pointer at the character after the 2.  If the next inputs are `bc` as in the sample input, scanf will return 0 (since `c` is not a digit) and your loop terminates.

Just stop using `scanf` and use `fgetc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would say that there is the issue in the logic of the program.
   At its simplest, it should be as follows

- Step 1: Input a string
- Step 2: Process the string (count occurrences of digits)
- Step 3: Output the result

  At the moment Step 1 and Step 2 are messed up together, and it makes things problematic.

2. If you need to process a string, you need to create it first, and you are not doing this in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
char s[100];
int count[10]={0};

// Input string
printf("Input a string: ");
scanf("%s", s);

// Process string and count digits
for (int i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if ( s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9' ) {
        count[ s[i]-48 ]++;
    }
}

// Output the result
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) printf("%d ",count[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: C provides character constants allowing `'0'` instead of 48 and `'9'` instead of 57. Your code may overflow `s`, and has quadratic runtime because it calls `strlen(s)` on every loop iteration. You don't check for errors from `scanf`.

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for pointing that out. I've just removed strlen.